# Convertion from 3D to 2D openGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, matrix

Few days ago , we learned about Homogeneous Matrices in OpenGL class.
From what I have understood , using these matrices we can convert 3D objects to 2D.
However , I am facing some difficulties answering a simple question like : "Which of those matrices answering to the definition of converting from 3D to 2D (Homogeneous)" :

[image]

```
           A                         B                      C               D
```

I'm not asking you to do my homework, I know the answer it's D and C and this is all I need for this section. I just want to understand why? how it works? why A,B not and C,D yes.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In matrix C you have an X scale factor of 1 at position (0, 0). You have a Y scale factor of 1 at position (1, 1). The Z scale factor is at position (2, 2) and it is set to 0. If you take any  coordinate and multiply it by the matrix, the Z-component ends up as 0. No matter what x and y are, Z will always be 0, so you've essentially flattened (or more accurately projected) all coordinates onto the XY plane. All 3D points become 2D points in the XY plane.

For matrix D, again, think about multiplying a point by the matrix. Since the first row is the same as the second row, the resulting x and y coordinates will always be the same. Therefore, every resulting coordinate will be on the x=y plane.

Whenever you create a matrix that, when multiplied by any point results in points that are on the same plane, you've converted from 3D to 2D.